# Why should I create my entity objects in the business layer?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, code-first, n-tier-architecture

i have one question about n-tier projects

I was watching a video lesson that teaches you how to create an application based on the principles of SOA .
First of all , a video class is old , or there was not the code first approach.

In the video , the developer took the entity objects to the business layer , since according to him, is not good we use the entity objects generated by default by the entity framework.

With this, the repositories created in the data layer , using the entity objects layer models instead of using the entity objects from data layer

This seems odd , if you think that the data layer depends on the business layer

This left me very confused , because I am using the code first approach and I had created objects entities in the data layer for the entity framework mapping them and the context class .

I imagined the following scenario :
presentation layer
    MVC Project consuming my classes in business layer .

business layer
    Classes consuming my repositories and units of work

data layer
    Entity objects , repositories , units of work , class of context

So why create the entity objects in the business layer ? ?

Sorry about my english, its google translator .

thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your entity objects should definitely be part of the Data Layer since they dictate the database structure (when using a code first approach). From what you describe it seems like that video is referring to some kind of `DTO` (Data Transfer Object) or possibly something along the lines of a `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you! I need learn more about the viewmodels and how to use them.
I saw something about and i have one doubt.

I must create my viewmodels in the presentation layer, right?!?!?!
Because this is a feature of the MVC. In fact, i dont need create viewmodels if i dont use MVC project, right???

Comment: @LéoJenkins MVC is just a pattern, so you want to remove any logic from your presentation layer (i.e, views), `ViewModels` are able to do this. So `ViewModels` are not just for MVC, there could be other patterns that require something similar.

Comment: @LéoJenkins You seem to mixup the two patterns MVC and MVVM. They are both meant for separating logic from views.

Answer (score 0):

In n-tier scenarios you separate the entities from the data access layer (DAL) into an extra assembly which you can share between client and server (shared assembly). The DAL is used on the server only whereas the entities are used on client and server.

Entities can be pure DTOs in order to carry data between the different tiers or they can contain business logic (data validation, calculated properties, business operations, etc.) which would make them be business components. Therefor you could see the business layer span two tiers (client and server) and your entities are part of it.